# combine conditions if browser window is X height and element is scrolled to X point within

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've started with the below which works perfect, but I only need this to run and execute when my nav element `.mainNav` is scrolled to within a certain point within browser height.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 660px) {
  .mainNav {
    margin-top:-130px !important;
  } 
}
```

So detecting vertical browser height **WITH** scroll position within then chain `.css` with jQuery to. (`margin-top:-100px`)

Basically how to combine above parameter with below parameter. Below detects scroll position...

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#some-element'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
    // user scrolled 50 pixels or more;
    // do stuff
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to check the scroll position using JavaScript and toggle a class on e.g. the `html` element depending on if the condition is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using the `clientBoundingRect` of the element. For example (untested, just theory);

```
var mainNav = document.getElementsByClassName('.mainNav')[0];

window.onscroll(function(e){
  if(mainNav.clientBoundingRect().top <= 100 && window.height <= 660){
    mainNav.style.marginTop = "-130px";
    // or you could add a class here, as per the suggestion above, such as
    // mainNav.setAttribute('class', 'mainNav locked');
  }else{
    mainNav.style.marginTop = "0";
    // and remove it here
    // mainNav.setAttribute('class', 'mainNav');
  }
})
```

Comment: I would not set the style directly on the element. Otherwise you would  need to do the check on both `resize` and on `scroll`  a better way would be to set the class and do the actual styling withing the style sheet. Another advantage would be that you then only would need to check for the `top` position, and do the ` window.height` only with media queries.

Comment: @t.nlese Good point. You could use the code mentioned in the comments instead whilst removing teh check for *&&window.height"

Answer (score 0):

There is no visbility pseudo-selector in CSS, so you're looking at implementing this using JS handing of the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) event on your element, and then toggling the right (sequence of) class(es) through the [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface, probably with [transition rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) in the CSS itself for the properties you want to be dynamic.